# WCF/RIA with one common set of CRUD methods

Tags: wcf, prism, ria

I am very new to WCF/RIA services. I am looking to build an application using PRISM/MEF where I can offer new plug-ins for the application from time to time. Now, my database structure is pretty much static. It will not see many changes during its life (but there still might be a few). The new plug-ins will use the entity classes exposed by the database.

My Question is when I create new plug-in controls, these controls might need some special server side methods to be run. Which would mean I update my WCF/RIA service to account for the new methods. I really want to avoid that and was wondering if it is possible to create a WCF service that has just 4 CRUD mehods. I can pass any entity to these methods and depending upon the type, the entity gets saved, updated or deleted. Also it lets me pass any kind of LINQ query to the get method and returns me the appropriate results. The goal is to avoid making changes to WCF service unless the underlying DB structure changes.

Whatever special methods I add to my plug-in, they could simply mean passing complex LINQ queries to the generic Get method and get the results on the client side. Most of entity management happens on the client. WCF becomes a simple (yet powerful) layer over my database that lets me access any entity and process any complex query based on client side LINQ queries.

Thanks,
M

Answer (score 0):

Have these 4 CRUD operations in a seperated Domain Service.